# Replace default "index of" page with custom page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, indexing, indexof

I honestly despise the style of the default "index of" page when there is no index file. I have created my own, but I don't know how to integrate using htaccess so that when there is no index file, it will display my custom "index of" page instead. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `options -indexes` so you'll get a 404. Then you can create a custom 404 page that does the directory listing.

Another thing you could do is define custom [header](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#headername) and [footer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#readmename) files. Apache will add these to the beginning and end of the autoindex's html.

Both solutions don't require you to add your script to every folder you want to have a custom index-of, like David's does.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a custom 404 page just for 404 not found cases. As with what David says, I reference the script from the root folder, so it will work no matter which folder it's in, so I can just use one script for all the index of pages I have.

Comment: I missed the part that allows absolute paths. Very interesting. Learned something new. Thanks for you comment.